# opentelemetry datadog exporter: how can use a kubernetes secret?

Tags: kubernetes, datadog, open-telemetry-collector

I am trying to configure opentelemetry to export logs to datadog. I am using the opentelemetry operator. I have the following yaml:

```
apiVersion: opentelemetry.io/v1alpha1
kind: OpenTelemetryCollector
metadata:
  name: opentelemetry-collector
spec:
  mode: statefulset
  replicas: 1
  config: |
    exporters:
      logging:
      datadog:
        api:
          site: "us5.datadoghq.com"
          key: "DATADOG API KEY HERE"
```

I have my datadog API key in a kubernetes secret. Is there any way I can inject that secret into the above at the place where I have "DATADOG API KEY HERE"?

I looked up the docs for this yaml but I didn't see an option to reference a secret in this workflow (although I did already see the option to use a secret in the helm-based non-operator-based opentelemetry installation workflow).

Comment: Helm templating is the main way that comes to mind. Just as a FYI you have to use DD's proprietary log collector if you want to integrate logs with APM.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach your secret in your statefulset to export it as env variable.
More on how to do it, [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#define-container-environment-variables-using-secret-data). And then in your config of otlm, you can access env variable as ${env:DD_API_KEY}.
Hope this helps.